# IIS Weak Cipher Suites

Tags: asp.net, iis, tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have few weak ciphers on my windows server 2012 but when I disable them my website stop working which is hosted on that server.
Can anyone help me what should I do that my website should be working after removing these ciphers
[image: These all are my weak ciphers showing in orange]

Comment: From the information you provided, I cannot be sure whether your website will work after deleting the ciphers. you can try it and If you get any problems during the process, please feel free to return to the discussion.

Comment: @samwu Thanks for the reply, I removed all the weak ciphers shown in the imaged I attached but as I mentioned in my comment website stopped working.

Comment: That’s obvious, you can’t delete weak ciphers.

Comment: @samwu The ciphers are weak ciphers, we would need to revamp those ciphers to use strong ciphers instead of the weak ones for security purposes. can you suggest me after removing these weak ciphers which strong ciphers I can add so that my website should not get affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try disable weak ciphers and then enable strong ciphers, but it should be noted that you have to choose a cipher suite that supports windows server 2012. for detailed information you can refer to this link:

[Cipher Suites in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel)

And here are some information about configuring secure cipher suites for your reference:

https://rootsecdev.medium.com/configuring-secure-cipher-suites-in-windows-server-2019-iis-7d1ff1ffe5ea

https://petri.com/cipher-best-practice-configure-iis-ssl-tls-protocol

Comment: Thank you @samwu, I saw the links you provided, the ciphers that are showing as weak on SSLLabs the lprovided ink says they uses the strong crypto. can you also please help me to find what other strong ciphers I can enable on the server apart from the strong ciphers that are already enabled on the server showing in green in my question.

Comment: Try this link: [https://www.ssl.com/how-to/require-strong-ciphers-in-windows-iis-7-5-and-8/](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/require-strong-ciphers-in-windows-iis-7-5-and-8/).

Comment: Hi @samwu, thanks I used last 2 ciphers mentioned in the link (https://www.ssl.com/how-to/require-strong-ciphers-in-windows-iis-7-5-and-8/) and it worked, sorry for the late.

Answer (score 0):

you want to disable all the other cipher except
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ?
Modern browser such as chrome and firefox don't support DHE cipher they just support ECDHE OR RSA cipher although firefox can enable DHE cipher in about:confige page but it just support TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA OR TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA