# ASP.NET WebService how to disable CBC Mode in TLS1.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, security, ssl

i´m builing a WebService and want it to be as secure as possible. I have tested the suporrted Ciphers via NMape. The result was this:

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A    
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp384r1) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A    
|     compressors:     
|       NULL    
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

Now i want to disable als Ciphers that include CBC Mode. How do i do this?
If the Server would be running on Linux i could create a new ciphersuite but on Windows i have no clue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS Weak Cipher Suites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941567/iis-weak-cipher-suites)

Comment: Pretty sure that's up to the actual HTTP Server, i.e IIS or Kestrel (self hosted ASP.NET Core), for IIS check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/restrict-cryptographic-algorithms-protocols-schannel), for Kestrel check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-default-supported-tls-protocol-versions-changed)

Comment: This does not realy help me. I´ve already used thsi " httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;" to determine the used TLS Version. And i have already disapled 3DES using the registry (SCHANNEL). But i can´t a method to disable CBC Mode.